# Translating relatively little known language

Tags: machine-translation

I want to build a model that does translation from some little known foreign language to English. No clue how to go about and wanted to get some advice.

Here’s what I have:

An old pdf (looks like something that was just scanned into a pdf so it’s kinda difficult) that has a word in the foreign language and Spanish and English translations

I estimated that it’s only about 3500-4000 words (a small dictionary)

My hope is to try to use a voice to text app to capture a speaker’s voice(speaking foreign language) and turn it into text. And then use the dictionary to make approximative translations and output that into a screen.

Basically,
Real-time translating apps use a combination of machine learning and artificial intelligence to translate text or speech from one language to another. The process typically works as follows:

1.The user speaks or types in a sentence or phrase in the source language.
2.The app uses a microphone or speech-to-text engine to convert the input to text.
3.The app uses a machine learning model to translate the text into the target language.
4. The translated text is displayed on the screen or if one wants to be ambitious spoken aloud by the app.

Seems simple but I feel like I would need to work on obtaining more data. Perhaps approaching hundreds of people or work with a team to somehow and more words and many sentence combinations?
What exactly would I need to do? and how realistic is it? Hoping to use ChatGPT4(haven't used it) or other LLMs